# Stop form from being resized with WPF Shell Integration Library

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using the WPF Shell Integration library in my WPF project to provide shell functionality in my borderless form. I am wondering how I can stop the form from being resized, but retain the forms ability to move and keep it's shadow? To create the form I am simply adding this to my XAML.

```
<shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <shell:WindowChrome
           ResizeBorderThickness="6"
           CaptionHeight="10"
           CornerRadius="0"
           GlassFrameThickness="1">
        </shell:WindowChrome>
    </shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add ResizeMode="NoResize" to the windows properties.

your xaml should look like this:

```
<Window x:Class="BorderLess.WindowBorderLess"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
   ResizeMode="NoResize" >
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome
       ResizeBorderThickness="6"
       CaptionHeight="10"
       CornerRadius="0"
       GlassFrameThickness="1">
    </WindowChrome>
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi Shahar. Thanks for replying. I should of mentioned that if I set the window to NoResize like above, then it removes the drop shadow from the form completely. Do you know how I can keep the shadow intact while removing the ability to resize?

Comment: I doubled checked with a new wpf project referencing .net 4.5. The drop shadow is still there even after setting to NoResize what framework. are you targeting .net 4?

Comment: Thanks for replying. No unfortunately I am targeting .net framework 4.0 and can not switch to 4.5. If only the shadow still appeared, then this would work for me. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: A while ago i came across this project on codeplex. Its really cool. I used it a few times. http://wpfborderless.codeplex.com .    it may be overshoot for your requierment but I am sure you could fit it to. Your demands.